# gcov warning: merge mismatch for summaries

Tags: c, gcc, gcov

Can anyone tell me what the gcov message "Merge mismatch for summaries" means? I have found the message in the gcc source here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5646/gcc/libgcov.c

It seems to be a sanity check that the tags in the `.gcda` files match, but I'm not sure.  Anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This happens when one of the objects you're linking into an executable changes significantly. For example it gains or loses some lines of profilable code.

The minimal case to produce the error is with 2 source files. Here are 2 example source files called main.c...

```
/* main.c */
int do_stuff(int value);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    do_stuff(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

and stuff.c

```
/* stuff.c */
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0
int more_stuff()
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    return i;
}
#endif

int do_stuff(int value)
{
    if (value > 1) {
        printf("Value > 1\n");
    } else {
        printf("Value <= 1\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What they do isn't important. To build them, here is a simple Makefile:

```
CFLAGS := -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
LDFLAGS := -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

testexe: main.o stuff.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The Makefile is set up so that the compilation is `main.c -> main.o`, `stuff.c -> stuff.o` and finally `stuff.o + main.o -> testexe`. If we compile and link those C files with the `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` options then the executable file has profiling. Run that execuatable and you'll get 2 output files, `main.gcda` and `stuff.gcda`. So far so good.

Now change the line `#if 0` to `#if 1`. The Makefile should cause just stuff.c to recompile, and the executable to relink. Next time you the test executable gets run you'll get the "Merge mismatch" message for the **main.gcda** file. The stuff.gcda file is not affected since its object file has been recreated with all the new summary information. If you recompile `main.c` and relink the executable, then the error message goes away.

So what can be done? I'd love to know! At the moment I run `find . -name '*.gcda' | xargs rm` whenever I need to re-check coverage, which is not really ideal. Another solution would be to recompile everything when using profiling "just in case", but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Great, thanks for the information!  It's nice to finally understand whats going on here.  Excellent explanation too.  I had a similar workaround - to delete all the generated files before running.  I now understand why this works but I think the error message could be improved somewhat.